Message Integrity Check Failure in android BLE application
I am developing android app for communicating with a BLE capable device.
The core functionality of the app is to read data from the device.
I am able to scan and connect to device but when reading large amount of
data (receiving chunks of data and reassembling),i am getting Message integrity check failure in between reading and connection is closing by bluetoothgatt object.
I have negotiated MTU before starting reading.
Please suggest if anything i am missing to properly configure connection.

Where/how exactly do you see this error?

@Emil,i saw in onConnectionStateChange callback status code as 61. I have also verified it with btsnoop log generated and viewed in wireshark

What chip/system/implementation is the remote device running? Have you tried running another android device from a different manufacturer or another remote device?

Make sure to use the newer onCharacteristicRead method of Android which gets the received BLE data as method argument. The old API where you get the data from a object field can cause problems when new data is received while you still process the received data (will cause data corruption).

@Robert, my use case is to write to a characteristic and receive nottification on another characteristic as response in onCharacteristicUpdate callback. One thing i noticed is even though i negotiated MTU (247 ),i am still getting chunks of 20 bytes in multiple onCharacteristicUpdate callbacks. In this call back i am checking no. of bytes received and sending next command only after i receive complete response for previous command.  Hope my use case is more clear now. Please suggest a better strategy to avoid MIC failure.

As there is no onCharacteristicUpdate in BLE API I assume you mean onCharacteristicChanged. For this method there is also a new version that gets the data as argument. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicChanged(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20byte[])

@Robert, yes i mean onCharacteristicChanged.
I am handling both versions of this callback.
